# Why do many of my parsley leaves have white tips?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, herbs, container-gardening, parsley

I'm not sure if this is normal? Not every leaf has this but lots of them do

[image: Parsley white tips]

Comment: Probably similar to what happened to your lettuce.

Comment: Thanks. So essentially this sounds like I should be just giving it more shade and less sun? The weather has been mid-upper 60's, but the humidity has been high (over 75%). I can't tell if it's the younger or older ones, but it seems to be the highest ones

Comment: 60's and 75%rh sounds great. Have you had a lot of wind?

Comment: Really, I think the plant looks fine, and wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Yep there is a fair bit of wind up here. The plant does look good! I just don't see tips like that when I buy parsely, so wasn't sure if it was something abnormal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a little wind. It won't affect the quality for culinary use, but possibly aesthetically as a garnish. Looks like Italian parsley, so not generally used as a garnish anyway. The plant looks quite healthy otherwise, so I wouldn't worry about it, but for next time, keep in mind that leaf tips on the outermost leaves are the most liable to sustain wind burn.

This is normal for many plants, not just parsley. To prevent it, you'll need to come up with a way to block the worst of the wind. Also, harvesting the oldest leaves first (the ones emerging from the outside of the rosette) will keep the plant growing, and keep the leaves fresh. There won't be as many blemished or yellowing leaves, and the plant will produce much more than if the plant is harvested all at once, even if allowed to regrow.